# To summarize total of string that appears in output in python

Tags: python, log-analysis

For instance, I want to show that how many times is Dest port number 53 is appeared, and there are 2000 datas in the log file, so I need to show each Dest port sum. This is my code :

```
def main():
    f = openfile("/Users/rin/Desktop/new sec/2017-04-18_010.082.012.003.txt")
    if f is None:
        print("File not found")
        return
    s = splitline(f)
    for el in s:
        if len(el) > 50:
            p = parselog(el)
            if "dstport" in p:

             print("Dest Port : %s" % p["dstport"])
             if "app" in p:
                 print("Apps : %s" % p["app"])
            print("")
```

Output :

```
Dest Port : 53
Apps : DNS

Dest Port : 123
Apps : NTP

Dest Port : 53
Apps : DNS

Dest Port : 53
Apps : DNS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    f = openfile("/Users/rin/Desktop/new sec/2017-04-18_010.082.012.003.txt")
    if f is None:
        print("File not found")
        return
    s = splitline(f)

    # add a counter
    counts = {}

    for el in s:
        if len(el) > 50:
             p = parselog(el)

             if "dstport" in p:
                 # increment counter
                 if p["dstport"] in counts:
                     counts[str(p["dstport"])] += 1
                 else:
                     counts[str(p["dstport"])] = 1
                 print("Dest Port : %s" % p["dstport"])
             if "app" in p:
                 print("Apps : %s" % p["app"])
             print("")

    # output the count
    for k, v in counts.iteritems():
         print 'Dest Port %s Count: %s' % (k, v)
```

Comment: Like I have 2000 port like this, so how can I take one by one to make the output?

Comment: @warezers updated, not sure about Python 3 syntax though